# É possível ter mais de uma Primary key em uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, chave-primária

Tenho uma academia e estou usando uma `Pk` para que todos os usuários da academia tenha o seu próprio (ID).

- É possível usar outras `PK` na mesma tabela?
- Por exemplo: para evitar que o `Número da Matricula` ou até mesmo o
  `CPF/RG` se repitam, é possível adicionar uma `PK` para os mesmos?

Comment: inclusive nem seria recomendado caso fosse possível, pense bem?

Answer (score 7):

Não não é possível ter mais de um `PK` em uma mesma tabela. Use Constraints (Restrições), no seu problema use a restrição [UNIQUE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp), que irá garantir que todos os valores da sua coluna sejam diferentes.

**UNIQUE**

- A restrição `UNIQUE` identifica de forma única cada registro em uma
  tabela de um banco de dados.
- As constraints `UNIQUE` e `PRIMARY KEY` garantem a unicidade em uma
  coluna ou conjunto de colunas.
- Uma constraint `PRIMARY KEY` automaticamente possui uma restrição
  `UNIQUE` definida.
- Você pode ter várias constraints `UNIQUE` em uma tabela, ***mas apenas uma
  Chave Primária por tabela***.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi agora!

Comment: @GuilhermeMoura bom que puder ajudar :) Ótima pergunta. Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais como funcionam as coisas por aqui.

Answer (score 3):

É possível usar outras PK na mesma tabela?
- Não, o que você pode usar é a PK de uma outra tabela como FK (Chave Estrangeira) de outra tabela. Outra forma possível também seria a utilização de uma chave primaria composta por 2 campos.
 Exemplo: 
TabItem
PK - idItem

TabTipo
PK - IdTipo

TabTipoItem
PK - IdItem
PK - IdTipo

Para evitar que o Número da Matricula ou até mesmo o CPF/RG se repitam, é possível adicionar uma PK para os mesmos?

Você pode utilizar o campo como Unique que desta maneira os valores não irão se repetir.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível ter mais de uma chave primária por tabela, ela é a coluna ou conjunto de colunas que identificam uma linha.

Para previnir que valores repetidos seja inseridos em determinadas colunas, torna ela um `unique key`.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade você pode ter duas ou mais chaves primarias em uma tabela no MySQL, inclusive uma chave estrangeira pode ser uma chave primaria na tabela definida.

Uma observação importante, geralmente campos autoincrement são chaves primarias por default. Então não crie um campo autoincrement antes de criar a chave primaria composta.

ex:

```
ALTER TABLE pedidoitem
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_unic_prod PRIMARY KEY (codigo,codigopedido,codigoproduto);
```

Após criar a chave primária você pode atribuir ao campo código a função `AutoIncrement`.

detalhe: `codigopedido` e `codigoproduto` são duas chaves estrangeiras

E campos de chaves primárias não podem ser nulos...

---

Segue a sintaxe exemplo:

PRIMARY KEY on CREATE TABLE - ID e Lastname são chaves primárias

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID,LastName)
);

PRIMARY KEY on ALTER TABLE

ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID,LastName);
```