# Proibir que linhas fiquem exatamente iguais no Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, chave-primária

Possuo um sistema que integra dados de Três bancos diferentes, mais especificamente o cadastro das empresas desses três bancos, criei uma tabela onde ficam armazenados as integrações que usuário vier a fazer, por exemplo:

```
no banco X a empresa A é código 01
no banco Y a empresa A é código 02
no banco Z a empresa A é código 03
```

na minha tabela que armazena as integrações que usuário for fazer o dado ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
nomeEmpresa = A
codigoBancoX = 1
codigoBancoY = 2
codigoBancoZ = 3
```

Eu preciso evitar que por descuido do usuário sejam adicionadas exatamente iguais todos os campos, ou seja não poderá ter duas linhas na minha tabela exatamente iguais. Minha pergunta é. Se eu colocar todos os campos da minha tabela como **Primary Key** iria solucionar meu problema? Pois assim nenhuma linha poderia ser exatamente igual mas mesmo assim poderiam existir linha assim:

```
nomeEmpresa = A
codigoBancoX = 1
codigoBancoY = 2
codigoBancoZ = 3

nomeEmpresa = A
codigoBancoX = 1
codigoBancoY = 2
codigoBancoZ = 4
```

Comment: Não use PK para isso, crie uma chave UNIQUE com as colunas relevantes.

Comment: Como eu faço isso no PostgreSQL tu saberia me dizer? Eu pensei que PK servisse para isso, para que fosse única a coluna

Comment: Relacionada: [É possível ter mais de uma Primary key em uma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214088/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-ter-mais-de-uma-primary-key-em-uma-tabela/214091#214091)

Comment: No Postgres não sei, mas certamente tem alguém aqui que sabe. PK é a chave primária, o identificador principal da linha. Geralmente não é legal que seja muito complexa. Semanticamente ela diferente do UNIQUE (embora implique UNIQUE).

Comment: @R.Santos fique a vontade para usar um [Indice Unico](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-unique.html) ou uma [Restrição Unica](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), se quiser saber a diferença entre ambos... [CLIQUE AQUI](http://flatiron.engineering/technology/2016/09/13/uniqueness-in-postgres.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como foi dito nos comentários, o correto na sua situação é utilizar um índice único.

Criar um `UNIQUE INDEX` no postgresql:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tabela_unique_idx ON public.tabela
  USING btree ("col1", "col2", "col3");
```

Referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-unique.html

Comment: Desse modo eu poderei adicionar por exemplo: `codigoBancoX = 1 | codigoBancoy = 2 | codigoBancoZ = 3` numa linha e na outra linha `codigoBancoX = 1 | codigoBancoy = 2 | codigoBancoZ = 4`?

Comment: sim, pode, a chave única com as, no seu caso, 3 colunas, só será violada se todas as colunas forem iguais.

Comment: Perfeito então, ultima coisa eu consigo executar esse comando depois que minha tabela estiver criada já?

Comment: sim, só não conseguirá executar se já houver dados que violem essa restrição.

Comment: Certo. E esse `USING btree` é padrão ou tem um motivo especifico para você ter usado?

Comment: esse é o `index method`, e sim o padrão, que é árvore binária. Há também os métodos `gin`, `hash` e `gist`, para mais informações pode ver na resposta do bigown nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101065/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-index-b-tree-hash-gist-e-gin

Answer (score 0):

PK identifica de forma exclusiva cada registro em uma tabela de banco de dados, UNIQUE recomendado para o que você precisa.e você tem que fazer o tratamento do erro em sua aplicação quando os registros forem idênticos.

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry 'valor' for key 'coluna_UNIQUE'

Answer (score 0):

Pela sua descrição, acredito que precise que cada campo tenha um valor unico, afinal não deve ter duas empresas no `banco X` com o mesmo `id`.

Para isto, deve criar uma Restrição única para cada campo.:

```
ALTER TABLE public.Empresas ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Empresas_codigoBancoX UNIQUE (codigoBancoX);
ALTER TABLE public.Empresas ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Empresas_codigoBancoY UNIQUE (codigoBancoY);
ALTER TABLE public.Empresas ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Empresas_codigoBancoZ UNIQUE (codigoBancoZ);
```

a sua segunda opção é utilizar um indice unico

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXU_Empresas_codigoBancoX ON public.Empresas (codigoBancoX);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXU_Empresas_codigoBancoX ON public.Empresas (codigoBancoY);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXU_Empresas_codigoBancoX ON public.Empresas (codigoBancoZ);
```

diria para criar um indice se este codigo for utilizado como condição em alguma consulta.

Comment: Desse modo eu poderei adicionar por exemplo: `codigoBancoX = 1 | codigoBancoy = 2 | codigoBancoZ = 3` numa linha e na outra linha `codigoBancoX = 1 | codigoBancoy = 2 | codigoBancoZ = 4`?

Comment: Não, pois viola a restrição no código x e y.

Comment: Pois mas o que eu preciso é isso, eu tenho que poder repetir os códigos só não posso ter as linha exatamente iguais

Comment: Tem alguma forma que eu possa fazer isso?

Comment: @R.Santos pela descrição da sua aplicação, me parece que o seu banco está mal modelado.

Comment: Mas o que você considera que preciso alterar @Tobias Mesquita?

Comment: No seu exemplo, se uma empresa pode ter mais de um `id` no `banco z`, então seria melhor manter um tabela com relacionamento de 1:N ao invés de manter todas as combinações em uma unica tabela.

Comment: O problema é que esses dados estão vindo de outros bancos