# Campo Unique Update com Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Como trato um campo unique na hora de fazer um update com hibernate.

Ele apresenta a msg de campo duplicado.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '41987523699' for key 'UK_4yakf5drp3py7vaalfeb1mrv7'
```

Comment: Um pouco mais sobre UNIQUE: [É possível ter mais de uma Primary key em uma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214088/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-ter-mais-de-uma-primary-key-em-uma-tabela/214091#214091)

Answer (score 0):

Isso é restrição do banco de dados. O Hibernate não pode tratar essa restrição. O que você pode fazer é retirar a restrição (cuidado com essa opção) ou verificar se já existe este campo restrito antes de um insert ou update